# Why are these Clojure lists different?

Tags: clojure

I'm running through some of the [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com) problems and hit some weird behavior with some of my code. Upon further investigation it seems the culprit was using the quote macro vs list function. Why does this matter in the code below, and why does it produce the incorrect result?

```
user=> (= (class '(/ 1 2)) (class (list / 1 2)))
true
user=> (def a '(/ 1 2))
#'user/a
user=> (def b (list / 1 2))
#'user/b
user=> (class a)
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user=> (class b)
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user=> (apply (first a) (rest a))
2
user=> (apply (first b) (rest b))
1/2
user=> (class (first a))
clojure.lang.Symbol
user=> (class (first b))
clojure.core$_SLASH_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have used the symbol object as function in expression `(apply (first a) (rest a))`. The symbol object looks for the value of itself as a key in a map:

```
('/ {'+ :plus '/ :slash '- :minus} :not-found)
=> :slash

('/ {'+ :plus '$ :dollar '- :minus} :not-found)
=> :not-found

('/ 1 :not-found)
=> :not-found

('/ 1 2)
=> 2
```

Answer (score 9):

```
'(/ 1 2)
```

is analogous to:

```
(list '/ 1 2)
```

When you don't quote `/`, you get its value, which is the built-in division function, rather than the symbol.